# How to get the name of forum post : discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

With my Discord servers now having access to Forum Channels, I want to extend my word checker bot to also check forum post names.

How would I get the forum post name/object?

Also, is there a way to do some sort of: `client.on("newPost", ...)`?

Comment: Forums are not supported in discord.js yet, I suggest have a look at the [PR](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/pull/7791)

Comment: I got it to work actually. Every forum post is a thread. Kinda weird but it works. I'll upload the code I used as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same question but I found the answer by searching on the Discord API page. The new Post event is a threadCreate event!

Also, the name of the thread is the name of the forum post. I didn't found yet how to get all images, emojis and the description but I think it will soon be added in Discord.JS!

Try this:

```js
const { ChannelType } = require('discord.js');

client.on('threadCreate', async (thread) => {
    if (thread.type == ChannelType.GuildPublicThread) {
        // When a new forum post is created
        console.log(thread.parentId) // The forum channel ID
        console.log(thread.id) // The forum post ID
        console.log(thread.name) // The name of the forum post
    }
})
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Update to Kodeur_Kubik's answer:

One must filter for new forum posts by checking the `thread.parent.type`

```
client.on('threadCreate', async (thread) => {
    if (thread.parent.type === ChannelType.GuildForum) {
        // When a new forum post is created
        console.log(thread.parentId) // The forum channel ID
        console.log(thread.id) // The forum post ID
        console.log(thread.name) // The name of the forum post
    }
    if (thread.parent.type === ChannelType.GuildText) {
        // When a new thread from a message is created
        // ...
    }
})
```

Not only has ChannelType `GuildPublicThread` been depreciated and replaced with `PublicThread`, this is actually referring to if a thread / forum post is public or private, as the name implies

[List of Channel Types](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/enum/ChannelType)